# Imgur, bad request on load image

Tags: jquery, ajax, post, imgur

I have written a code that allows me to display the image once selected by the form, and then load it automatically on imgur with api.

Works only the function to display the image , when I send upload's request , it returns error 400.

Code to load image:

```
if (file.files && file.files[0]) {

            console.log('caricamento immagine: '+file.value);

            $.ajax({ 
                url: 'https://api.imgur.com/3/image',
                headers: {
                    'Authorization': 'Client-ID (my id)'
                },
                type: 'POST',
                data: {
                    'image': file.value
                },
                success: function(data) { 
                    var uri = data['upload']['links']['imgur_page'];

                    console.log(uri);
                }, 
                error: function(e) {
                    console.log(e); 
                }
            });

            return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It may be because the URL for uploading images has a different endpoint than the one for requesting them. Try changing your URL in the AJAX request to:

```
url: 'https://api.imgur.com/3/upload'
```

Also make sure that the data for the `image` attribute is either a Base64, Binary or a URL for the image you are trying to upload. Otherwise you will get an error. Additionally, you should  tell Imgur which type you are using, for instance, if you Base64 encode the image your data object should look like this:

```
data: {
    image: 'ZmlsZW5hbWU=', // example base64 string
    type: 'base64'
}
```

Defining the type is not required, but it make shorten the time it takes for uploading because it doesn't have to parse the string.

The specification for the API can be found [here](https://api.imgur.com/endpoints/image#image-upload). You can also check out this PHP function for [`base64_encode()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php) if you want to go that route.

Comment: Unfortunately I get again the same error. Now my code is this: `image: btoa(file.value)` I used the function **btoa()** that encodes a string to base64. This is the answer to the request: `{"data":{"error":"Image format not supported, or image is corrupt.","request":"\/3\/upload","method":"POST"},"success":false,"status":400}`